# Setting timezone of org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm just getting started with org-mode, and really like it so far. I work in London with xemacs running on OpenVMS based on the East Coast US. Is there any way to get org-mode to use a timezone other than the server's default?

I've tried:

```
(setq calendar-time-zone 0)
(setq calendar-standard-time-zone-name "GMT")
(setq calendar-daylight-time-zone-name "GDT")
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out:

```
(set-time-zone-rule "GMT-1")
```

works.

I'm not entirely clear why this:

```
(set-time-zone-rule "BST")
```

gives the wrong output (it results in times 1 hour early, even though BST is the current timezone string for London, UK).

Comment: It turns out `(set-time-zone-rule)` expects a path in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` (at least on GNU/Linux), as you might set your `TZ` environment variable to.  E.g. `(set-time-zone-rule "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul")`

Comment: I know this was an eternity ago, but for new visitors: the problem with BST was likely because it is neither a current nor deprecated zone name in the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

While you can use raw offsets, for someone living in an area with daylight saving, picking an appropriate place name will save you the hassle of changing your zone twice a year. For those living in Great Britain, `Europe/London` is the current canonical name.

Answer (score -1):

```html
(set-time-zone-rule "<TZ*>")
```

where

```html
<TZ*>
```

is a canonical value from [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)